Tabulator mutator cell function will not allow data grid to load
Tabulator mutator function blocks the display data grid. Formatter works fine. Possible mutator function written incorrectly or possible bug in program. Tried every combination of (cell, value, data) in mutator function.
Please help.
 {title:"NOWVolume2", field:"nowVol2", width:"6%",  
 mutator:function(value, data) {
 var newValue = cell.getValue();
 var old = cell.getOldValue();
 return newValue - old}}, 
 MUTATOR DOES NOT WORK, when the word *cell* is in variable, grid will not load. 


 {title:"NOWVolume2", field:"nowVol2", width:"6%",  
 formatter:function(cell) {
 var newValue = cell.getValue();
 var old = cell.getOldValue();
 return newValue - old}},
 FORMATTER WORKS.
  
  


You should read the docs Mutators where it will tell you what the function signature is and what the parts of the signature are.
